# IdentityServer UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication and UseCookieAuthentication in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, identityserver3

I have a large-ish enterprise web application that consists of multiple actual ASP.NET mvc/web api websites.

I have the authentication setup for the MVC websites very similar to the sample here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MVC%20Authentication

I have a scenario where the flow is not what I am expecting and I am hoping someone can tell my if I am doing something wrong or if my expectations are wrong.

Lets consider two web applications using the same identityserver. Lets call them App1 and App2.

When a user first arrives at App1 they are redirected to the identityserver login screen where they login and are they redirected back to App1.

When they go to the App2, they are also redirected to the identityserver, but since they are already logged in through the identity server they are sent back via the "Please Wait" screen.

So far so good, exactly what I would expect. But when the user goes back to App1 I expect that they are already authorized through a cookie on App1, but it redirects them to the identityserver and back through the "Please Wait" screen. Is that expected or is something wrong in my setup?

Comment: are the apps hosted on the some or different domain ?

Comment: They are hosted on the same IIS with the identityserver at the root and each application as a subsite on that website, so they are on server/app1 and server/app2

Comment: Are App1 and App2 using same cookie name for the cookie which ASP.NET creates in the cookie middleware?